# Particle instance modifier problem

Tags: particles

I have been using Blender for about four months and wanted to stretch myself by doing a more advanced tutorial. I have followed the below one but at 8.08 the particles I create simply spray out in an arc instead of creating the explosion pattern. All my settings seem to be the same but l am clearly missing something. Pls help.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=TiblXutqw08

Thank you.

Comment: Is your emitter on the same layer as the drag force field? Setting the gravity field weight to 0.0 will stop particles falling down.

Comment: I believe l have duplicated the drag force field so it is on later one and three. And l can generate the objects from the particle instance modifier but the actual particle system doesn’t seem to be following he modified pattern.